What criterion to use to compare multiple correlations of binary variables?
I have $N$ definitions of certain properties of countries (for example, if the country is "democratic", "totalitarian" etc.), and want to test how consistently different people understand these definitions. For that, I create a questionnaire containing for each definition $k$ yes/no questions of the form "Does the following country satisfy the definition above?", followed by a "de-personified" description of a country. My null hypothesis is that all definitions are equally consistent, and the alternative hypothesis is that some of the definitions is more or less consistent than the rest. By consistency I mean "how much classifications performed by different people correlate one with another".
My questions are: 1) What correlation metric should I use, and 2) What statistical criterion should I employ to test homogeneity of correlations?
UPD: I've realized there was a mistake in my original description of the problem (besides, it was not clear enough), and have rewritten the question from scratch.

This sounds like interrater agreement with binary ratings.

Yes, thank you for the name, looks like the thing I need

I think the problem might be that your formulation of null-hypothesis is not actionable. 'Question formulated less clearly than the rest' ... how would one derive something computable from it?
You could try formulating this as, all students are exchangeable, so probability of $i-th$ question to be answered as yes is $\pi_i$, i.e. each answer to i-th questions from m-th student is $A^{(m)}_i\sim Bernoulli(\pi_i)$. In which case the number of yes-answers from $M$ students will be distributed as $Y_i\sim Binomial(M,\,\pi_i)$. The probability distribution for $\pi_i$ will then be given by Beta distribution. If you want to stick to frequentist methods your null hypothesis would be $Y_i\sim Binomial\left(M,0.5\right)$ (if I understood your definition of 'not formulated clearly'). For a good alternative hypothesis you will need to specify just how far away from $\pi_i=0.5$ a clearly formulation has to be (as a minimum).
Not sure whether the description above captures what you were talking about, but it might be a good idea to try to represent whatever you are thinking in a way I did. You can then actually compute what you are after.

Thanks for the attempt! Unfortunately, your idea does not help me for two reasons. The first (and a minor one) is that initially I did not formulate the problem the way I meant it. I've since rewritten the description from scratch. I hope, the new problem statement is more clear, too. The second is that, since I don't know myself if the definitions are consistent, I cannot presume a specific proportion of "yes" and "no" answers. Therefore, there is no reason to expect that, given $H_{0}$, the binomial distribution should have a specific value of its parameter $p$.
